# Can accuracy be applied on a subset of test data?

Tags: python, accuracy

I have 52 samples in my test data. They gave me an 80% accuracy score. My question is if I were to pick randomly for example 10 rows and give them to a friend. Can I state that these 10 rows follow an 80% accuracy? if not what should i do?

Other metrics are not important to me now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot state that every sub-sample will have the same accuracy (i.e. distribution of correct vs incorrect classifications) for the following reason.

Imagine you had 100 samples with 80% accuracy. Now imagine you give 20 samples to your friend. If you are very unlucky you will give them the exact 20 samples that your model classifies.

This unlikely outcome has a probability nonetheless of:

$P = \frac{{20}\choose{20}}{{100} \choose{20}} = 1.87e^{-21}$

The next natural question is: How sure can I be that the accuracy will be 80%?

Well the larger the size of the sub-sample the more closely it will resemble the population from which it was sampled.

Comment: that is an extremely small number. therefore i can assume that my subsample has the same accuracy?